# UITextField crashes if changing text in editing changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I wrote a simple ios5 application (includes garbage collector) that has a single view and a `UITextField`
I need to analyze input text in this `UITextField`
here's my code.
header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;

-(IBAction)editingChanged:(UITextField *)sender;
```

`editingChanged:` tracked with send event editing changed so this method calls everytime user changes something in my `UITextField`

part of implementation file:

```
#pragma mark - textField

-(NSString *)stringWithoutAbc:(NSString *)sourceString
{

    NSString *resultString=[sourceString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"abc:" withString:@""];
    if (![resultString isEqualToString:sourceString])
    {
        NSLog(@"    sourceString: %@", sourceString);
        NSLog(@"    resultString: %@", resultString);
    };
    return resultString;
}

-(IBAction)editingChanged:(UITextField *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"editing Changed. text: %@", sender.text);

    //removing "abc:" from string in text field
    NSString *str=[self stringWithoutAbc:sender.text];

    //if something was removed - changing text in text field
    if (![str isEqualToString:sender.text])
    {
        sender.text=str;
    };
}
```

Everytime user changes text in `UITextField` we remove "abc:" strings from this text using standard `NSString` method.

The problem is: the application is unstable. It sometimes crashes when "abc:" gets removed.
Help me please. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Usually crashed when 2-3 times "abc:" gets removed at the begginning (or at the end) of the typed text. And the we type "abc:" in the middle of typed text in `UITextField`

Comment: Have you checked for NSZombie's with Instruments?

Comment: Garbage collector? In iOS? Do you mean ARC?

Comment: I'm launching profiling (instruments app) -> memory -> zombies. Of course there are some memory allocations. How can I see if there are zombies?

Comment: There is a tick box to be ticked, then you run your software until it crashes. Instruments will tell you if it detects a zombie and guide you to the responsible line.

Comment: I thought so. There's no zombies detected in this app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below `textField`'s delegate method :-

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
```

Comment: If i use this delegate method I hope _my_ problem will be solved **but** it is strange that I can not use `UITextField`'s send actions for this very simple task

Comment: If the text gets edited in "editing changed" send action of `UITextField` the app will be unstable. Is it a bug or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Arc, you don't have to retain the object. And btw, ARC is not garbage collector. 
http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/
MAybe because you use retain on the textField.

Comment: No, my code will not even compile if I use retain, release etc. in ARC mode

Comment: You have this: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;